Why does tar command create this directory structure when extracting a tar file?
I have created this simple directory structure:
$ tree testdir/
testdir/
├── subdir1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
├── subdir2
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── file4.txt

and would like to archive the contents of testdir into a tar file. So I run the following command (note the exclude is because of this answer):
tar cvf /home/myuser/testdir/testdir_tarfile.tar --exclude=/home/myuser/testdir/testdir_tarfile.tar /home/myuser/testdir

Now I want to extract the files (along with their directory structure) once again. So first create a target directory:
$ mkdir /home/myuser/testdir/target_dir

and now extract the tar file to the target directory:
tar xf /home/myuser/testdir/testdir_tarfile.tar -C /home/myuser/testdir/target_dir/

The resulting file structure looks like this:
$ tree testdir/
testdir/
├── subdir1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
├── subdir2
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── file4.txt
├── target_dir
│   └── home
│       └── myuser
│           └── testdir
│               ├── subdir1
│               │   ├── file1.txt
│               │   └── file2.txt
│               └── subdir2
│                   ├── file3.txt
│                   └── file4.txt
└── testdir_tarfile.tar

Why does the target directory now contain subfolders "home" and "myuser"? I would like it to just contain "subdir1" and "subdir2", i.e. like the original archived directory.


Why does the target directory now contain subfolders "home" and "myuser"? I would like it to just contain "subdir1" and "subdir2", i.e. like the original archived directory.

You also need to use the -C option during compression. E.g.:
tar -cvf "$HOME/testdir_tarfile.tar" -C "$HOME" testdir

which is basically equivalent to:
( cd && tar -cvf "testdir_tarfile.tar" testdir )

As can be seen from the verbose output, note that this creates a TAR containing relative paths:
testdir/
testdir/subdir2/
testdir/subdir2/file2.txt
testdir/subdir2/file1.txt
testdir/subdir1/
testdir/subdir1/file2.txt
testdir/subdir1/file1.txt

If you want to create a TAR with absolute paths, or have such a TAR, and need to extract it, then you need to extract it by stripping the prefix like this:
tar -cvf "$HOME/testdir_tarfile.tar" "$HOME/testdir"
mkdir -p "$HOME/testdir/target_dir"
tar --strip-components=2 -xf "$HOME/testdir_tarfile.tar" -C "$HOME/testdir/target_dir/"
tree "$HOME/testdir/target_dir/"

/home/user/testdir/target_dir/
└── testdir
    ├── subdir1
    │   ├── file1.txt
    │   └── file2.txt
    └── subdir2
        ├── file1.txt
        └── file2.txt

4 directories, 4 files


Great, thanks. Didn't realise the -C option could be used on creation as well as extraction.
